# Unable to run the app after obfuscate the code with Babelfor on MacOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, obfuscation

I'm trying to obfuscate my Xamarin.Forms app, the android one, with Babelfor .Net on MacOS; I tried several times and everything goes ok, at least some important assemblies are obfuscated.

The main problem comes when I try to run the obfuscated app and doesn't work. Any idea?

I tried other methods like Dotfuscator successfully, but the client want's to use Babel instead; also a new "Hello World" project with Babel just to be sure is not caused by the main project.

By personal reasons I'm not able to access to a Windows pc to try MSBuild option or Babel in there.

This is my terminal line:

```
babel MYAPP.apk --keystore KEYSTORE.jks --keypass KEYPASS --storepass STOREPASS --keyalias STOREALIAS
```

Also I tried the basic:

```
babel MYAPP.apk
```

Here is a Pastebin with my output for the "HelloWorld" project.

[Output Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/M7XgZYVa)

Comment: why not to ask Babelfor support? you pay for it.

Comment: I already did it but meanwhile want to know if someone had a similar trouble